# Freebsd shutdown privileges

Tags: permissions, freebsd, users, user-permissions

I need to create a user and deny them permission to turn off the machine.

DO SOMEONE KNOW HOW TO CHANGE THE PERMISSIONS OF A NORMAL USER TO NOT ALLOW ME TO TURN OFF?

Comment: What software is installed?  Do you have a GUI or something?  I doubt a unprivileged account could shutdown a minimal cli-only system.  How are they shutting down the system?

Answer (score 4):

Use of `shutdown` requires a privileged account.

From freebsd.org's [documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/boot-shutdown.html):

> One must be root or a member of operator in order to run shutdown(8).

If the user has sudo rights, you can forbid access to shutdown, reboot, poweroff and halt by modifying `/etc/sudoers` something like this:

`username   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL, !SHUTDOWN`

or

`%groupname   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL, !SHUTDOWN` to disallow a group.